# UDP Message not being Received

Tags: c#, udp, udpclient

I have a very simple UDP listner (coded in C#, copied from the net). That works on my computer.

The issue is a friend of mine want to use it, but when he runs it NO message is received.

```
public static void rec_udp()

{
    bool done = false;
    string str_ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
    int listenPort = 11000;



    using (UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(listenPort))
    {
        IPEndPoint listenEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(str_ipAddress), listenPort);

        while (!done)
        {
            var remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(str_ipAddress), listenPort);
            byte[] receivedData = listener.Receive(ref remoteEndPoint);

            Console.WriteLine("Received broadcast message from client {0}", listenEndPoint.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("Decoded data is:");
            string gillian = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedData);

            string[] x = Regex.Split(gillian.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", ""), @"<([^:]+):\d+[^>]*>").ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedData)); //should be "Hello World" sent from above client

            string kayleigh = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedData);
           
            TextReader djb = new StringReader(kayleigh);
            string decoded = "";

                
            decoded =  Regex.Replace(kayleigh, @"\\u[0-9]{4}", ",");


        }
    }
}
```

I am at a lost as to why it works for me but not him.
I know he has setup the UDP sender correctly

Any ideas would be grateful

Thanks

Comment: Firewall settings? What platform is this being run on?

Comment: What does the sender look like? Is the port in use?

Comment: The platform is windows 10, 

Firewall setting is my guess, but I have little knowledge on how to check or what to look for

Comment: The sender is another program. So have little knowledge of how it is written.

You can setup a UDP outbound message and port, which has been done.

How do I check if the port is in use??